# Disable the camera at a low level on a MacBook Air with Ventura

Tags: camera, ventura

I'm paranoid and I want to disable the camera as thoroughly as possible short of altering the hardware. But I can't seem to find a method that works on Ventura. The closest lead I got was altering permissions on `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/VDC.plugin/Contents/MacOS/VDC`, but this fails with `Operation not permitted`, even with `sudo`. I don't really know what's going on; I'm a Linux guy.

Comment: Just my thoughts, but any software method to disable the camera can be reversed in software. Either rely on a physical solution (*very* thin cover or otherwise) or rely on the built-in camera controls in macOS.

Comment: @Ezekiel You have a point, but if I've removed a file necessary for the camera to run or something, I don't expect it would be reversed short of bona-fide malware. I'm confused that the built-in controls don't seem to have a global option to disable the camera, just per-application switches.

Comment: If a piece of hardware is recognized by the operating system (which it is), it can be accessed.  There’s no file you’re going to remove that breaks this connection.  A “low level” approach to this is to put a piece of tape over the camera.  No software can overcome that.

Comment: @Alan has the best suggestion - tape. The reason you can't remove files from the system volume is because it's signed & sealed. Nothing will let you alter files on it. If you ever manage to, by accessing it when the OS isn't running, it will demand you re-install the OS at next boot.